# When does a real function together with its derivatives form a basis?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider real functions defined on an interval, let's say $[-\pi,\pi]$. Let $s(x)$ be an analytic, periodic function such that all of its Fourier components are non-zero. We build a set of functions from $s(x)$ and all of its derivatives:

S=$\{s(x),s'(x),s''(x),\dots\}$

What is the condition for $S$ to be a basis?

By "basis" I mean that if I take any $f(x)\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ and produce a series of functions $f_N(x)$ which are the projections of $f(x)$ to the subspace spanned by the first $N$ elements of $S$, then $f_N(x)\to f(x)$ in $L^2$ norm.

What I understood is that if we want that $S$ be a basis, then it is necessary that all Fourier components are not zero. But is this enough or is there some other condition for $s(x)$?

I did not get far with any proofs. All I understand is that if I take the first few members of the set and I project to the space constructed from the first few Fourier components, then we will have a basis there. But I can't go further.

Comment: I have a couple questions. What is a Fourier component? I'm unfamiliar with that term. Is it the same as a Fourier coefficient? Second, for which vector space are you trying to determine that $S$ is a basis? Is it $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$? You say you don't know which vector space to consider. Are you interested in any other vector spaces?

Comment: $S$ is going to be countable. Is the dimension of your space countably infinite?

Comment: If the space is separable, like $L^2$ is, we can ask whether S spans a dense subspace. (In which case we could Gram Schmidt to get an ONB.)

Comment: Bryan, Yes, by Fourier component I mean Fourier coefficient. And yes, the space should be $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$. I am not interested in pointwise convergence, so convergence in $L^2$ norm should be fine. Basically that is why I did not consider other spaces.

Comment: Jonas, yes indeed, that is what I am looking for. The same answer applies to Gerry's question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed enough to assume that all Fourier coefficients of $s$ are non-zero.

The problem actually seems to become quite simple after a Fourier transform: Since $s$ is assumed to be holomorphic on a neighborhood of $[-\pi,\pi]$, we have that $\widehat{s}(k) = O(e^{-2\delta |k|})$.

In terms of the Fourier transforms, our task is to show that the vectors $(k^n \widehat{s}(k))_{k\in\mathbb Z}$, for $n=0,1,2, \ldots$, have dense linear span in $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$. This is the case: I'm going to use the fact that we can do weighted uniform polynomial approximation on $\mathbb R$ with respect to an exponential weight $w(x)=e^{\delta |x|}$ (this is perhaps an overkill; the result is discussed in *Koosis, The logarithmic integral I*). In particular, for any finitely supported sequence $b_k$, we can find a polynomial $p(k)$ so that
$$
\sup_{k\in\mathbb Z} \left| \frac{b_k}{\widehat{s}(k)} - p(k) \right| e^{-\delta |k|}< \epsilon .
$$
In other words,
$$
\left| b_k - p(k)\widehat{s}(k) \right| < \epsilon\, |\widehat{s}(k)|e^{\delta |k|} ,
$$
and this means that I can make $\|b-p\widehat{s}\|_2$ arbitrarily small: first take a ridiculously small $\epsilon$ to keep things under control as long as $\widehat{s}e^{\delta |k|}$ is not small, but eventually this term will take over and make everything exponentially small.

Comment: I tried this approach myself, but I did not know about your "overkill" fact.

Comment: Yes, my original comment might be off, this could be exactly what the problem is about...

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $s(z)$ has period $T$ and is analytic on the strip $|\mathrm{Im}(z)| < a$ for some $a>\pi T$. Then I claim that

- The derivatives $s^k(z)$ are dense in the space of all $T$-periodic functions BUT
- Said derivatives are not linearly independent.

I can not currently figure out whether the condition that $a>\pi T$ is necessary or an artifact of the proof method. By rescaling $T$, we may (and do) assume that $T=1$ for this rest of this answer, so we are assuming $a>\pi$.

**The linear relations between the derivatives:**

I claim that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2k+1} (2k+1)!} s^{(2k+1)}(z)=0.$$
I remark that this is only one of many relations, and in particular the simpler relation $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+1)!} s^{(2k+1)}(z)=0$ also holds if $s$ extends to a wide enough strip. But that simpler relation requires (or at least my proof of it requires) $a>2 \pi$ rather than $a> \pi$.

We first compute, then justify. Let the Fourier series of $s$ be
$$s(z) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k e^{(2 \pi i) mz}.$$
Then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{s^{(2k+1)}(z)}{2^{2k+1} (2k+1)!}  = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ c_m (m \pi  i)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} e^{(2 \pi i) mz} = $$ $$\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} c_m e^{(2 \pi i) m z} \frac{e^{m \pi i} - e^{-m \pi i}}{2} = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} 0.$$

These formal manipulations are justified if the double sum at the end of the first line is absolutely convergent. The first few steps of our bound are easy:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \left| \frac{ c_m (m \pi  i)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} e^{(2 \pi i) mz} \right| = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} |c_m| \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\pi |m|)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} \leq \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} |c_m| e^{\pi |m|}.$$

Now, $c_m = \int_0^1 s(z) e^{-m(2 \pi i)z} dz$. Since $s(z)$ is periodic and analytic on the strip $|\mathrm{Im}(z)| < a$, we may slide this integral up to a line segment at height $b$ for some $b \in (\pi, a)$ and deduce $c_m = O(e^{-m b})$. Sliding down instead, we get $c_m = O(e^{-|m| b})$. So $\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} |c_m| e^{\pi |m|}$ is bounded by a multiple of the geometric series $\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{(\pi-b) |m|}$ and we are done. $\square$.

**Spanning** To show that the derivatives of $s$ span the periodic functions, it is enough to show that their span contains $e^{r (2\pi i) z}$, for any integer $r$. Define
$$g(u) = (-1)^r \frac{e^{u/2} - e^{-u/2}}{u-r(2 \pi i)}$$ 
and let
$$g(u) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k u^k.$$
Then the same formal manipulations as above show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k s^{(k)}(z) = \sum_{m=\infty}^{\infty} c_m g(m(2 \pi i)) e^{m (2 \pi i) z}.$$
But $g(m(2 \pi i))$ is $1$ for $m=r$ and $0$ otherwise, so we have shown that $e^{r (2 \pi i)z}$ is in the span of the derivatives.

To justify the formal manipuluations, one needs a bound like $|b_k| = O(1/(2^k k!))$. You should be able to get this out of a contour integral on a square of side length $2k$, but it is a bit of work so I'm going to hold off writing it up until I know whether you actually need it for something. (And until I see whether someone comes up with a better method which allows any positive $a$, not just $a > \pi$.)

Comment: David, in the actual example that I was considering, $s(x)$ could have poles arbitrarily close to the real axis.

Answer (score 1):

$L^p$ spaces for $1\leq p\leq \infty$ are complete normed vector spaces. Also, $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ has infinite dimension since $\{1, x, x^2, \ldots\}$ are linearly independent.

Now the key part: no infinite dimensional, complete normed vector space has countably infinite dimension. This follows from the Baire Category theorem. As a rough sketch of the proof, suppose $\{v_1, v_2,\ldots\}$ were a countable basis. Set $X_i=\text{span}\{v_1,\ldots v_i\}$. Then

- $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty X_i$
- $X_i$ is *closed* in $X$ since it is a complete subspace
- $X_i$ has empty interior since it is a proper subspace
- $X$ is a Baire space since it is a complete metric space

These four observations lead to a contradiction. In particular, your countable set $\{s(x), s'(x), s''(x),\ldots\}$ is not a basis for $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$.

Comment: This is if by 'basis' you meant 'Hamel basis'.

Comment: Given that the OP is talking about Fourier series it seems much more likely they are concerned with Schauder bases.

Comment: I thought that too, but since he wasn't entirely sure which space he was considering I thought it might be up for debate. We'll wait for OP to see. I am looking into a Schauder basis.

Comment: What I mean by basis is the following. I take any $f(x)\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$. Let us denote by $f_N(x)$ the projection of $f(x)$ to the linear space spanned by the first $N$ elements of $S$. My question is, whether $f_N(x)\to f(x)$ in $L^2$ norm. I just read Wikipedia, and it seems that this requirement is what the Schauder basis is.

Comment: You might want to add these details to your question. It'll help future answerers.

Comment: OK, thanks, I just did that.

Comment: A friend of mine pointed out that my requirement for $S$ to be a "basis" is weaker than the definition of the Schauder basis. If we expand any vector in a Schauder basis, then the coefficients of the basis vectors have to be unique. We don't require this here.

What we need is that finite linear combinations of the vectors of $S$ are dense in $L^2$.